# How to implement Glicko-2 rating system in a scalable way?

Tags: algorithm, multiplayer, ranking

I have a multiplayer game that, similar to chess, will have a win/tie/lose outcome in a 1v1 setting.

I've been looking at [Elo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system) versus [Glicko & Glicko-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glicko_rating_system) and it seems Glicko-2 might be a good one to try to implement. However, I am confused on how to build Glicko-2 in a scalable way.

It seems that I have to load all games & players into memory in order to calculate the new ratings of players in a match.

From my understanding, the ratings/deviation are supposed to change the longer a player hasn't played... From my understanding the algorithm 'auto' changes the deviation for players who haven't played.

Is there a kind of O(1) way to apply a glicko rating to the two players of a game and maybe daily run some type of 'decay' on everyone's ratings confidence (for those who haven't played) in a mathematically accurate way?

I'm leaning on sticking with Elo but I know many games have scaled Glicko-2, so I want to try to find a way to do that.

Comment: If I'm reading the algorithm correctly, it looks like after each match, you can immediately calculate new rank and deviation values for each player involved in that match, using their previous R & RD values and their time since their previous match. So if that's the case, you don't necessarily need to do any batch processing with all players in memory at a time. Am I missing or misunderstanding something?

Comment: Where does the time since come into play in the algorithm? I guess I'm looking at  implementations like https://github.com/animafps/glicko2.ts and https://github.com/KenanY/glicko2-lite . These libraries seem to just accept the results not necessarily accept any time aspect...

Comment: Time powers the decay mechanic. In the Wikipedia link above, it's the variable `t`.